# replacement has length zero error in R programming of a no claim discount scheme

Tags: r

I tried to run this code in R to calculate the revenue a company makes from premiums after n years but I keep getting the replacement has length zero error. (power_of_TM is a function to multiply matrices that works fine )

```
    NCD = c(1,.85,.70)
    base_premium = 200

 

    p = numeric(0)
    prem<-function(n){
      for (i in length(NCD)) {
        p[i] = mean(power_of_TM(n)[,i])
        base_premium*sum(p*NCD)
        
      }
    }
    
    #check for n=5
    
    prem(5)
    
    premium=numeric(0)
    for (n in 1:20){
      premium[n]=prem(n)
    }
    Error in premium[n] <- prem(n) : replacement has length zero
    premium
    numeric(0)
```

Comment: I can't run any of your code because you haven't provided the `power_of_TM` function. But it seems like `prem(n)` returns a 0-length result for one of your inputs. Check the current `n` value after you get the error - that's the `n` that causes the problem. Then you can debug your functions for that particular `n` and figure out why it's returning a 0-length result.

Comment: The issue is that your function always returns `NULL`. Maybe `base_premium*sum(p*NCD)` should be put outside of the for loop?